# Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Unable to obtain SASL authenticator)

Tags: jakarta-mail, apache-tomee, james

I have rather unique setup. I am not sure if others have tried this. 
I have the following VirtualBox setup. 
Host is a OS X (Maverick)
Guest is Windows 7 64 bit.

I have an apache james-2.3.2 running on the Guest. I have several users on this james server. I have not configured ssl. I have set the DNS to be my home routers ip address.

I also have port forwarding setup on my vm. Host port 10025 -> Guest port 25.

On the host I have installed thunder bird. When I send email from one account to the other I can see the other james user receiving the email. I have use localhost as the host for all my accounts in Thunderbird.

Now, I have a apache tomee running on the host with an ejb that needs to send out an email. Following is my config for the mail session in tomee.xml

```
 <Resource
    id="xyz_mail"
    type="javax.mail.Session"
>
    mail.transport.protocol=smtp
    mail.smtp.ssl.enable=false
    mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=10025
    mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
    mail.smtp.host=localhost
    mail.smtp.port=10025
    mail.smtp.auth=true
    mail.smtp.user=user1
    password=user1
    mail.smtp.password=user1 (added just for the heck of it, things don't work with out without this line)
    mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
    mail.smtp.timeout=5000
</Resource>
```

My java code in the ejb is the following

```
public class NotificationManagerImpl implements NotificationManager {


@Resource(name = "xyz_mail")
Session xyzMailSession;

public void sendMessage(String addressTo, String subject, String messageText) {
    try {
        logger.info("Attempting to send Message to [" + addressTo + "].");
        properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.user"), properties.getProperty("password"));
        Message message = new MimeMessage(xyzMailSession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("user2@abctech.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(addressTo));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(messageText);
        abcMailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport.send(message);
        logger.info("Message sent to [" + addressTo + "] successfully.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error when sending an email", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This code fails to send out an email. Following is the debug output and Exception.
**My question is why do I get this error when Thunderbird is able to send and receive emails just fine?**
**This what I see when I do telnet**

```
MacBook-Pro:ayx_mobile ajayamrite$ telnet localhost 10025
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**Error with JavaMail reference implementation**

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.2
#
#Sun Aug 31 22:00:31 BST 2014
mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
mail.smtp.ssl.enable=false
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
mail.smtp.host=localhost
mail.smtp.timeout=5000
mail.smtp.port=10025
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=10025
mail.smtp.user=xyz
password=xyz
mail.smtp.password=xyz
ServiceId=xyz_mail
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true

DEBUG: SMTPTransport trying to connect to host "localhost", port 10025

DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 
DEBUG: SMTPTransport could not connect to host "localhost", port: 10025

Aug 31, 2014 10:00:36 PM abc.NotificationManagerImpl sendMessage
SEVERE: Error when sending an email
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 10025
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:899)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:158)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at abc.NotificationManagerImpl.sendMessage(NotificationManagerImpl.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

**Error with geronimo implementation.**

```
Loading javamail.default.providers from jar:file:/Users/ajayamrite/Downloads/apache-tomee-abc-core/lib/geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.8.2.jar!/META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtp, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtps, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPSTransport, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=nntp-post, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.nntp.NNTPTransport, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=nntp-posts, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.nntp.NNTPSSLTransport, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=nntp, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.nntp.NNTPStore, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=nntps, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.nntp.NNTPSSLStore, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.POP3Store, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3s, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.POP3SSLStore, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imap, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.IMAPStore, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imaps, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.IMAPSSLStore, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0 Loading javamail.default.providers from jar:file:/Users/ajayamrite/Downloads/apache-tomee-abc-core/apps/abcCoreEAR/lib/javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615.jar!/META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtp, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtps, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTSransport, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=nntp-post, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.nntp.NNTPTransport, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=nntp, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.nntp.NNTPStore, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3, className=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.POP3Store, vendor=Apache Software Foundation, version=1.0
Loading javamail.default.providers from jar:file:/Users/ajayamrite/Downloads/apache-tomee-abc-core/apps/abcCoreEAR/mail.jar!/META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imap, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore, vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtp, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport, vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store, vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc, version=null
DEBUG: getProvider() returning provider protocol=smtp; type=javax.mail.Provider$Type@4c3b0d83; class=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport; vendor=Apache Software Foundation;version=1.0
smtp DEBUG: Failing connection for missing authentication information

smtp DEBUG: Attempting plain socket connection to server 127.0.0.1:10025
220 bedouinvm SMTP Server (JAMES SMTP Server 2.3.2) ready Mon, 25 Aug 2014 11:53:29 +0100 (BST)
EHLO Ajays-MacBook-Pro.local
250-bedouinvm Hello Ajays-MacBook-Pro.local (10.0.3.2 [10.0.3.2])
250-PIPELINING
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
smtp DEBUG: Processing extension PIPELINING
smtp DEBUG: Processing extension ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
QUIT
221 2.0.0 bedouinvm Service closing transmission channel
Aug 25, 2014 11:53:29 AM co.uk.abc.core.interfaces.impl.NotificationManagerImpl sendMessage
SEVERE: Error when sending an email javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Unable to obtain SASL authenticator)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:163)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
at co.uk.abc.core.interfaces.impl.NotificationManagerImpl.sendMessage(NotificationManagerImpl.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:180)
at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:80)
at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:181)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:370)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:181)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:344)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:240)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:86)
at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a hunch I turned off the firewall on the guest Windows 7 machine briefly. The email sending worked, so it was the firewall on the guest that was causing problems.
I turned on the firewall again (Don't forget to do this) and created a Inbound Rule on the guest to allow connections to the port 25 (only on my private network).
The email sending is now working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [JavaMail reference implementation](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) instead of the GNU version.

Comment: I tried with the JavaMail reference implementation but it does not work. I just get a different text in the error message. Edited the question to show the stack tract with this implementation.

Comment: First, what happens when you use telnet on the host machine to connect to port 10025?

Comment: Second, this debug output "DEBUG SMTP RCVD:" should **NEVER** occur with JavaMail 1.5.2.  The code that produces that message has been commented out for several releases.  The fact that you're getting that message suggests that you have a configuration problem, perhaps with two versions of the JavaMail classes on your CLASSPATH.  I'm not sure that explains your connection failure, but it may be the source of other problems.

Comment: I have removed the geronimo mail jar file from the lib folder. The only Mail implementation is the reference implementation. I have updated the question to show the telnet output.

Comment: If that's all the output you get from telnet, then something is wrong with your mail server or the way you're forwarding ports to the mail server.  The mail server should display a greeting message as soon as you connect to it.  JavaMail should time out in 5 seconds (as you've configured) waiting for the greeting message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following command line option: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

It solved a similar connection issue for me.